# Mysqli searching value in multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to search for Value1 that could  be in Field1, Field2 or Field3.  I know my syntax is wrong because it's obviously not working, but here was my crack at it:

```php
$query = "SELECT *
   FROM table1
  WHERE city = '$city'
    AND state = '$state'
    AND location = '$location'
    AND (field1 = '$field1U' OR field1 = '$field2U' OR field1 = '$field3U')
  ORDER BY date_created LIMIT 5";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

I thought maybe I could use where field1 in (1,2,3) but I couldn't get it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all of the records where:

`field1 = someValue`

or `field2 = someValue`

or `field3 = someValue`

then you can use this:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE city = '$city' AND state = '$state' AND    location = '$location' AND (field1 = '$Value1' OR field2 = '$Value1' OR field3 = '$Value1') ORDER BY date_created LIMIT 5";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
AND (field1 = '$field1U' OR field1 = '$field2U' OR field1 = '$field3U')
```

with

```
AND (field1 = '$search' OR field2 = '$search' OR field3 = '$search')
```

(notice i'm searching for field1, field2 or field3)
but please, please, please (!!) escape those $search strings! for example:

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $search)
```

where $link was set using

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...)
```

please refer to http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
this is used to prevent SQL Injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

oh, and try to split the text from the variables, as i personally, think that's safer and better coding style. for your use case:

```
AND (field1 = '" . $search . "' OR field2 = '" . $search . "' OR field3 = '" . $search . "')
```

Comment: What is $search set as, sorry if that's a stupid question.  And the data is being pulled from a table where the fields were already escaped, I would that should be ok right?

Comment: `$search` is the "Value1" from your question. you don't need an escaped value in your database, but in your query. read about SQL Injection on wikipedia.